# JavaFX - Label format changes spontaneously

Tags: javafx, format, label, fxml

First of all, let me apologize for not including code. I tried to reproduce this issue with a smaller project but was unsuccessful. The issue itself is sporadic as well, so it is difficult for me to nail down the culprit.

Basically, what is happening: I have my UI defined in FXML and it includes several labels throughout, some of which I have set the font to "Bold."

```
<Label text="Appetite Info:">
    <font>
        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0"/>
    </font>
</Label>
```

The problem is that, as the user clicks around the UI, all of these labels will be reset to "Normal" font weight. Sometimes it is giving focus to a text field or scroll pane, other times it happens just when the main UI window loses focus.

I do have the application styled with CSS, but this happens even with a `Default.css` that doesn't override any formatting:

```
.root {

}
```

Has anyone else noticed this behavior or know where I should look for a solution?

Comment: Where do you set your labels to bold? Do you use `setStyle()` method? Please provide FXML and CSS lines related to your bold labels.

Comment: I've seen spontaneous style-changes in JavaFX before, but sadly could never pin-point the cause or narrow it down enough to report a bug.  Things I've seen are controls suddenly using "disabled" style, while still being enabled and functioning, and some glyphs reverting to squares, while other instances of the same glyphs in the same scene are still correctly showing.

Comment: I've edited the question to provide the code snippets in question, @SergeyGrinev

Comment: Incidentally, I have noticed that if I specify the font with -fx-font-weight instead, the issue does not happen at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll mark this as answered. Styling all my nodes with CSS instead of through the FXML markup solves this issue.